# NoClassDefFoundError: DataAccessException using spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I know this has been discussed a lot, but somehow none of the previously asked questions is applicable to my case.
When loading my application I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3067)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2521)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
at de.festo.rs.windows.FXApplStarter$1.run(FXApplStarter.java:29)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$55/29905907.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$54/20965065.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$46/6575340.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

In most of the threads I read concerning similar errors people were indeed missing the spring-tx jar which I definately don´t.
It is declared in my maven dependencies along with the other spring jars neededd like this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

When investigating my deployed output the jars are there as well.
Nevertheless the mentioned error is thrown. I am really desperate with this.
Please note, that the application is not a WebApp but kind of a standalone application loaded from another program.

Funny thing is that my colleague can´t reproduce the error. For that reason I guess it´s some kind of race condition between my JavaFX loader loading the result of the spring-jdbc query into its datamodel. I don´t have any proof for this, it´s just kind of a gut instinct.
Any help or tipp would be really appreciated.
If further information is needed please let me know.

Comment: How are you running the code? This seems almost certainly to be a classpath issue.

Comment: try to add [spring-dao](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao/2.0.3) to your pom.xml

Comment: I load my JavaFXApp using the FXMLLoader which then has a reference to its controller like this:

`fx:controller="foo.bar.Controller"`

which in turn loads the spring jdbc template:


`this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(DatabaseConnectionFactory.getDataSource(system));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class : `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` is defined in Spring-DAO. Check if have below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That did the trick now, although I could swear I tried that before with the other jars in version 4.1.7.
What really confuses me, though, is that the spring-tx.jar also contains the DataAccessException class.
Also I´m not sure why maven is not loading this as a dependency, when building the app.

Why could my colleague not reproduce the error using the exact same settings?

Comment: @Wingie .. I am not sure how it is working for your colleague. As maven automatically download all the dependent libs for your dependencies so spring-dao may be downloaded in your colleagues case and not your. But thats weird.

Comment: That´s why I was so desperate with this. When I deployed the app and started it, I got the error. When he started it (using my deployed app, not his own) it worked.
I even got it running myself using my c drive rather than using a share to load the files.
For that reason I assumed some kind of race condition.

Comment: To update on this again:
I removed the spring-dao dependency few days ago and dind´t have any problems running the code anymore.
This is still a mystery to me.

Comment: I am having same issue here. I am not even using spring-data still I am getting this error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I encountered this issue when I deleted spring-dao and spring-tx in the local  springframework repository. I was trying to sort of have a clean install of my project but its throwing an error that it can't find my services even though the file is actually there. Anyhow, after deleting those spring directories and adding this to my pom file. It's now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

to fix this issue i have just moved the application.java under the base package like i have created groupid `demo.test.activemq` and created the same package name in `src` folder and then restarted. it works for me.

Comment: the `Main.java` with `public static void main` has to be in some package

Answer (score 2):

Another posibility is, that you hide some dependencies through a **`scope`** like test:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Just remove the scope (or set the default: compile)